# AutoMapper EF6 ProjectToList<T> "Method not found"

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I'm using the Automapper (v10) and Automapper EF6 (v2) library for the first time (I've used AutoMapper successfully before) with EF6.4 and I'm getting a weird issue with the following line of code

```
using (DashboardEntities db = new DashboardEntities())
            return db.Dashboards.ProjectToList<DTO.Dashboard>();
```

Really just want to get all entities from the DB, but mapped to DTO objects so I can keep the UI and Data projects distinct and not have an EF6 reference in my UI project.

The above snippet builds but throws a runtime exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon> 
AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.ProjectTo(System.Linq.IQueryable,
 System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<System.__Canon,System.Object>>[])
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6) gives an example using an Async version of the above method, but in my scenario, I don't want this.
I don't get why I'm getting this MissingMethodException at runtime

I could use the basic Automapper library and add some lines of code, but that defeats the purpose of the AutoMapper EF6 plugin and also reminds of [this blog](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code) post I saw a while back

Thanks in advance for any insights

Comment: You have a version mismatch. Probably because you use AM 10. You should use AM 8. If you want to update that package to work with the latest AM, a PR is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In the ProjectToList method, try to pass in the IConfigurationProvider. For example:

```
db.Dashboards.ProjectToList<DTO.Dashboard>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```